# Contar lineas python

Tags: python, spyder

Tengo que implementar una función que cuente el numero de palabras de un fichero y si en una linea hay dos palabras iguales a las introducidas solo lo cuenta una vez y tengo que ir contando cuantas hay.

Mi código :

```
def contar (filename, words):

    for w in range(len(words)):
        words[w] = words[w].lower()
    with open (filename,'r' ) as f:
        fichero = f.readline().split()
    total = 0
    for linea in fichero:
        if w in linea :
            total +=1
    return total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero unas observaciones:

```
fichero = f.readline().split()
```

lee una sola línea del fichero, por lo que:

```
for linea in fichero
```

iteras sobre las palabras de la linea (salida de `str.split`).

Por otro lado:

```
if w in linea
```

comprueba si `w` (que en tu caso es la última palabra de las ingresadas sin convertir a minúsculas) está en la línea, debes comprobar si alguna de ellas está, no solo una. La comprobación es a la inversa.

Por otro lado, convertir en minúscula solo las palabras a buscar no es suficiente, debes convertir también la linea para que ambas estén normalizadas y puedas comparar.

Como por cada línea solo te interesa conocer si hay al menos una, debes romper el ciclo en cuanto el condicional se cumpla.

```
def contar(filename, words):
    words = set(word.lower() for word in words)

    total = 0
    with open (filename, 'r') as fichero:
        for linea in fichero:
            for palabra in linea.lower().split():
                if palabra in words:
                    total += 1
                    break
    return total
```

Comment: vale gracias y una duda el ```set``` para que se utiliza

Comment: `set` sirve para construir un conjunto a partir de la lista, a diferencia de una lista se implementa mediante tablas hash, no tiene orden y sus items son únicos, es similar a un diccionario (dict) pero sin valores. La gracia en este caso es que las búsquedas (`if x in conjunto`) son mucho más eficientes que en una lista (en la que hay que iterar elemento a elemento). El código funcionaría igual con una lista, solo que sería algo más lento. Aquí tienes un enlace a la documentación oficial : https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset.